# Call View Method from Button in Menu in Shell

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

I am using Template10 for UWP application that I am creating. I am using the Hamburger template. I would like to have a secondary button in the hamburger menu that calls the refresh method of the active view.

My plan was to place a normal button in the secondary commands of the hamburger menu and in the onclick event call the refresh method. I will have an interface on all my views with the refresh method so each view will have the method.

What is the best way to get a reference to the active view so that I can call the method from the onclick event in the shell?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, we can add a `HamburgerButtonInfo` in `HamburgerMenu.SecondaryButtons` like:

```
<Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo x:Name="RefreshButton" ButtonType="Command" Tapped="RefreshButton_Tapped">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <SymbolIcon Width="48" Height="48" Symbol="Refresh" />
        <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Refresh" />
    </StackPanel>
</Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
```

Then in code-behind, we can add an `Event` in `Shell` class such as `RefreshEvent`. And in other views, we can subscribe to this event. When we click/tap the refresh button, we can invoke this event to perform the refresh. For example:

In Shell.xaml.cs

```
public event Action RefreshEvent;

private void RefreshButton_Tapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshEvent?.Invoke();
}
```

And in MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
{
    if (suspensionState.Any())
    {
        Value = suspensionState[nameof(Value)]?.ToString();
    }

    Views.Shell.Instance.RefreshEvent += Refresh;

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}

public override async Task OnNavigatingFromAsync(NavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    args.Cancel = false;

    Views.Shell.Instance.RefreshEvent -= Refresh;

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}

private void Refresh()
{
    //TODO
}
```

Here I used the ViewModel for example, you can also implement this in the code-behind of your view. But please note that we need to subscribe to `RefreshEvent` when we navigated to a view and unsubscribe from it when we leave the view so that the `RefreshEvent` only reference to the active view.

Comment: Thanks Jay! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A perfect recommendation, Jay. Textbook perfect.

Comment: @JohnSullivan Glad to know it helps. So is it an [acceptable answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for your question?